# coredns containers are running on only one master

Tags: kubernetes

I have setup Kubernetes HA cluster with 3 masters. Version 1.14.2. Observed that 2 coredns containers are running on only one master. If I stop this Master, coredns is stopped. Are there any configuration to spawn this to remaining masters?

How can I spawn the coredns containers to the remaining masters.

Comment: Those pods are managed by a replicaset. Don't they get rescheduled?

Comment: Yes, these pods are rescheduled on the remaining nodes.  Initially I was checking on Masters only, later observed that these pods are getting rescheduled.  Thank you

Answer (score 0):

you need to deploy dns autoscaler. and then tune autoscale parameters.
follow the link 
https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/administer-cluster/dns-horizontal-autoscaling/

follow the steps

```
kubectl apply -f https://raw.githubusercontent.com/epasham/docker-repo/master/k8s/dns-horizontal-autoscaler.yaml

kubectl get deployment --namespace=kube-system

kubectl edit configmap dns-autoscaler --namespace=kube-system

Look for this line:
linear: '{"coresPerReplica":256,"min":1,"nodesPerReplica":16}'

updae min value to 2 as shown below
kubectl edit configmap dns-autoscaler --namespace=kube-system
linear: '{"coresPerReplica":256,"min":2,"nodesPerReplica":16}'

you should get two coredns pods listed as below

master $ kubectl get po --namespace=kube-system|grep dns
coredns-78fcdf6894-l54db          1/1       Running   0          1h
coredns-78fcdf6894-vbk6q          1/1       Running   0          1h
dns-autoscaler-6f888f5957-fwpgl   1/1       Running   0          2m
```

Comment: Thank you for the quick inputs.  will deploy dns autoscaler.